# color pointer HTML5, event on mouseup

Tags: javascript, html, colors

I am using the standard HTML5 color picker. To reduce data, I am trying to send the hex value on a mouse up event. Something like:

```js
function doSomething(value){
  console.log(value);
 }
```

```html
<input type="color" id='xyz' value="#FFFFFF" onmouseup="doSomething(this.value)">
```

I read, that there are two events available: oninput and onchange. I think the onchange value would be the one I am looking for, but it doesn´t work. I am working with javascript.
Here in the code snippet, the value is sent with a click on the small color window. That would be fine for me. On my Computer the value is sent with the move of the mouse. What is different here?
Thanks fo any help!

Comment: `onchange` is the correct event to use. If you want to rate-limit events, you should use a debouncing code. For example, queue it to send 1s after a change event, but cancel that if another change event comes in.

Comment: Why do you need to get a color in a function on event `onchange`? In this case, the previously selected color will be sent every time you select a new color again. This is not logical! Better do it with a regular button.

Comment: I want to avoid an extra button. But I will try both approaches! Thanks for your help!